# mmenu button not working

Tags: jquery, html, mmenu

Unable to get the `mmenu` button to show. I get a link "Open the menu" and "Close the menu". There isn't an icon like on the tutorial. There was a post about this already, but that did not help. I followed it and get the results that I stated above.

Here is what I have:

```
     <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"         CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>          
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/src/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/jquery.mmenu.all.css" />  


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#my-menu").mmenu({
                "counters": true, "classes": "mm-light"       
                });

                });
          </script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function () {
               $("#my-menu").mmenu();
               $("#my-button").click(function () {
                $("#my-menu").trigger("open.mm");
            });
        });
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#my-menu").mmenu();
            $("#my-button").click(function () {
                $("#my-menu").trigger("close.mm");
            });
        });
</script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="#my-menu">Open the menu</a>
        <a href="#my-menu">Close the menu</a>


        <div id="page">     
            <!-- The menu -->
      <nav id="my-menu">
         <ul>
            <li "><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li "><a href="/about">About us</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a></li>
                  <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any html in there to create a button. The tutorial talks you through how to set up the Javascript for triggering the menu on a click action - which you have in your code:

```
    $("#my-button").click(function () {
        $("#my-menu").trigger("close.mm");
    });
```

But since there is no element #my-button, that code is redundant. And in their examples they use links anyway. All you're really missing is some CSS to make the link look like a button. There's an example in the mmenu download. This is the relevant html from that example:

```
    <div class="header FixedTop">
        <a href="#menu"></a>
        Demo
    </div>
```

and the css is in demo.css under `.header a`

Any css for a suitable button would do the trick, though.

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rtzfof74/) based on your code, with the working button. Hopefully that splits out the html, css and javascript in a way that makes it easier to see what's going on.

These are the changes I made to get the button working:

- Removed some of the javascript which we don't need - it's just
  confusing the issue!
- Removed the open and close links, and replaced them with the header
  menu code from above. Changed the id from `#menu` to `#my-menu` to
  match the html.
- Copied in the css for `.header a` from the demo. This is what makes our menu link look like a button. In reality, it's just a link like your original open and close links.
- Copied the css for `.header,.footer` from the demo. This just gives
  our header bar a nice contrast so that we can see the white button
  clearly.
- Added a simple style rule to make the header fixed to the top.

So in the end, the functional parts of it - the HTML and Javascript hardly need to change. It's all about the CSS stylesheet making those links look different.

Comment: Being a newbie to js...could you possible give code?  I just copied the .header a to the jquery.mmenu.all.css file and put the code you have above  in place of                                                      <a href="#my-menu">Open the menu</a>
        <a href="#my-menu">Close the menu</a>                                                                                                                                       It shows the word Demo in the upper left hand corner.  I'm not sure where to apply all the coding for a button.  This is my first menu I'm trying to get to work.  Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Here's a fiddle which puts it all together: http://jsfiddle.net/rtzfof74/ I updated my answer with an explanation. The button is a bit of a red herring - it's really just a link like the ones you have already. Just needs that css to style it. Also since the icon is white, you need a contrasting backgroundd to be able to see it. Hope that helps.

Comment: That is awesome!  I understand it a lot more and appreciate the time and explanation...this is great!  Thank you very much!